# Unable to Select list from Dropdown on IE8

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-8

Good day. I have issue with IE8 `<select>` dropdownlist. I'm unable to access, click or select an item from the list on the dropdown. as soon as I place my cursor in the list, the list hides away. This happens on IE8 only i tried to use `<!--[if IE 8]>` to target IE8 only but I can't seem to fix this issue. I believe that this is just `<html>` and `[CSS]` fix.
Basically I want the drop down to delay a bit so that the user can select the options inside the list. here is my link to [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/aWLLa/)

here is my html:

```
<dl id="checkout-payment-method-load">
    <dd>
        <ul style="" id="payment_form_cybersourcesop" class="form-list">
            <li class="field">
                <label class="required" for="cybersourcesop_cc_type">Credit/Debit Card Type<em>*</em></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <select class="required-entry validate-cc-type-select" name="payment[cc_type]" id="cybersourcesop_cc_type" autocomplete="off">
                            <option value="">--Please Select--</option>
                            <option value="001">Visa</option>
                            <option value="002">MasterCard</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </li>
        </ul>   
    </dd>
</dl>
```

here is my CSS:

```
.checkout-onepage-index .form-list select{
margin: 0 2px 30px 0 !important}

.form-list select{
margin: 0 10px 0 0;
width: 175px;}

select{
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
border: 1px solid #1B191A;
box-shadow: 0 0 2px 0 #1B191A inset;
color: #555555;
font-family: 'foco_corpregular';
font-size: 13px;
height: 25px;
padding: 2px 0 0 5px;
transition: border 0.2s linear 0s, box-shadow 0.2s linear 0s;}



label, select, button, input[type="button"], input[type="reset"], input[type="submit"],input[type="radio"], input[type="checkbox"] {
cursor: pointer;}
```

here is the image

[image]

Comment: Could you show your HTML?

Comment: Are there any CSS and Javascripts related to the dropdown?

Comment: http://fiddle.jshell.net/aWLLa/ my link to fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Try using Internet Explorer's developer tools (F12 on your keyboard) to access the element selector tool (it's an icon that looks like a cursor). Then wave your cursor around that area and see if there's an element that is blocking it.

Odds are that element with the credit card number is overlapping.

You can also go through and deselect applicable styles on the live page, and see if anything allows the drop-down list to become selectable. Then you know which style is interfering.

Answer (score 0):

Good Day

I have resolved this issue by adding the following css inside the `<head>`

```
<!--[if IE 8]><style>
 select{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #1B191A;
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px 0 #1B191A inset;
    color: #555555;
    font-family: 'foco_corpregular';
    font-size: 13px;
    height: 5px;
    padding: 2px 0 0 5px;
    transition: border 0.2s linear 0s, box-shadow 0.2s linear 0s;
}
```

thank you to those who contributed :)